# img tag proper in firefox but in IE it is showing the image at the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hi i have the following code in my html.

```
<html>
    <tr>
    <td>
       some code here...
    </td>

    <td align="left" valign="top" width="35%">
        <img    src="http://ocs.landsend.com/lebowebcontent/images/global/marketing/TrueValue_SHIP_IMG.jpg" onerror='this.src="http://ocs.landsend.com/lebowebcontent/images/global/marketing/Stand_Ship_UPS_or_USPS.jpg";this.onerror=""' />
    </td> 

    </tr>
</html>
```

the image have to be displayed in the second column at the top of the screen but it is diplaying the at the bottom in IE.. but it is working fine in firefox and chrome.

Please help..

Comment: You have a syntax error, `<tr>[...]</tr>` must be used inside `<table><tr>[...]</tr></table>` tags. Also, you have no header and no body :/

Comment: please specify which IE version(s) you're testing with.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the doctype and IE is less permissive. Put this at the beginning of the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Hi i have all that.. what i have given is not the complete code.. the problem is with the image.. rest all is good..

Comment: @danny-london - it's not about IE being "less permissive", it's because a missing doctype tells IE that you want to use quirks mode. in any case, that isn't the problem here.

Comment: @SwethaMukka - if this isn't the complete code, you probably shouldn't have included the `<html>` tag in the question; it makes it look like it is the complete code, and changes the answers you might get.